# React how to efficiently deliver functions to events

Tags: jsx

I'm using a functional component of react, and I'd like to ask how to efficiently deliver functions to events.

See this article at https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

According to the official documentation, "Using an arrow function in render creates a new function etch time the component renders, which may break optimizations based on Strictity composite."

If there is no argument passed to the function, I understand that the check1 code is not a good code, is that right?

```
const Foo = () => {
  const example = () => console.log("hi");

  return {
    <div onClick={() => example()}>click1</div>
    <div onClick={example()}>click2</div>
  }
}
```

Is there a difference in performance between click1 and click2?

Comment: See the answers to the linked question. But just a side note: Since `example` doesn't pay any attention to any arguments it's passed, you can save a function allocation by doing `onClick={example}` instead of `onClick={() => example()}`. That means `example` will get passed the event object for the event, but since `example` doesn't pay any attention to it, to makes no real difference.

Comment: \* *it* makes no difference (doh!)

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the `arrow` functions only, declare any function in the component scope whenever the component rerenders it will re-initialize, to stop that from happening, you need to save the function referance, and that's happen when you use `useCallback` hook to wrap your function.

```
const example = useCallback(() => console.log("hi"), []);
```

And you can add the function dependencies to the array which second parameters to the `useCallback` hook, and whenever any of the dependencies change, the function will reinitialize to get the newest value of the dependencies.

[For more resources.](https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need to memoize a function, it will re-render every time and it's fine. Memoizing functions requires a memory cost, it's not free.
A common situation where you need useCallback is when you pass your function as a dependency to useEffect.

```
const fn = () => {}

useEffect(() => {
  fn();
}, [fn])
```

In this situation you don't want to call useEffect on every render, so you should wrap `fn` in useCallback. And it will be the same on every render

[Read more](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) or any article on "why I shouldn't use useCallback"